# How does deleteObject: work in coreData?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I just took the plunge and rewrote my App on top of CoreData (previously I was using my own internal save format).

Things are mostly working, although I'm a little confused by the behaviour of deleteObject:.

I have an object that is part of my graph, and when I delete it nothing seems to happen to the object. The object has relationships where some of them are "Cascade" and some are "Nullify". Every relationship to / from the object has an inverse relationship.

After I delete the object, the only thing that seems to change is that the "isDeleted" flag is set on my object. All of the relationships exist as they did before.

If I try to find the objects using a NSFetchRequest, it does not find the deleted objects. However, if I traverse my graph using the KVC relationships, the NSSet returned contains all of the objects including the deleted objects.

After I send the save: method to my ManagedObjectContext, then everything is as I expect.

When I do a deletion, do I need to manually nil out relationships I don't want or do I need to continuously save to keep my data sane? This seems very counter intuitive to me.

Is there anything that I can do to "commit" the deletion or at least make my object graph sane short of doing a save. It seems a little drastic to be doing a save every time I want to modify my graph.

Thanks,
Ron

p.s. Here is some of the behaviour that seems strange to me:

Before deleting the object, this is the "description" of the parent object which has a categoryObjs "to many" relationship:

```
categoryObjs =     (
    "0x613e1a0 <x-coredata://1A1AE9E7-66B1-4F4D-A7AB-07D4504CAE2C/TestCategory/p9>",
    "0x613e1b0 <x-coredata://1A1AE9E7-66B1-4F4D-A7AB-07D4504CAE2C/TestCategory/p12>",
    "0x613e190 <x-coredata://1A1AE9E7-66B1-4F4D-A7AB-07D4504CAE2C/TestCategory/p7>"
);
```

After deleting the "p12" object (the middle one above), the state of the relationship does not change when accessed through KVC. If I try to fetch the TestCategory entities, then only two are found.

After a "save:" the p12 object disappears:

```
categoryObjs =     (
    "0x613e1a0 <x-coredata://1A1AE9E7-66B1-4F4D-A7AB-07D4504CAE2C/TestCategory/p9>",
    "0x613e190 <x-coredata://1A1AE9E7-66B1-4F4D-A7AB-07D4504CAE2C/TestCategory/p7>"
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you call `save:`, your Managed Object Context must go back to the store and actually write the changes. This is expensive. Therefore, `deleteObject:` merely marks the object as deleted, which will actually be applied the next time you save. (Remember that this helps out with undo functionality too, it's just going against the way you want to do things.)

According to the documentation, the `isDeleted` property just states whether the object is going to be deleted upon the next commit, and sets an `isDeleted` flag on the object. Additionally, `deleteObject:` will remove the receiver from the context if it was never committed.

For example (where Objects A and B are `NSManagedObject` instances):

1. Create Object A
2. Save MOC
3. Delete Object A

Object A has been marked for deletion but is not actually deleted until you perform step 2 again.

Contrast with this:

1. Create Object B
2. Delete Object B

Object B is gone, since it was never saved, there is no "marking for deletion". It's simply gone.

**Edit:**

I'm just curious, are you using an NSFetchedResultsController for your tableview's datasource? It's worth looking in to, if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I'm still very confused. If I delete an object, I want it to not show up in my app. For example, I have a table of objects. The user deletes an object from the table and I send a "deleteObject:" message to my context to delete that object. I would expect that object to not appear in the table. I could manually check for the isDeleted attribute, but this is very tedious and also extremely error prone. To make things worse, this behaviour seems to be inconsistent. Sometimes the object disappears and other times the object does not.

Comment: It sounds like you are misunderstanding the concept of the `deleteObject` method. It doesn't actually delete an object. If you want to confirm the delete, than yes, go ahead and call save. Also, I'm just curious, are you using an NSFetchedResultsController for your tableview's datasource? It's worth looking in to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not using NSFetchedResultsController right now - I could look into it, although there are many places where I iterate over the objects. So is there really no way to actually delete an object without doing a save:? One of the reason that I converted over to CoreData was to have it automate a lot of this behaviour for me. Do I need to do it manually anyway? I don't care if the object is actually removed from disk or memory, but I do want a way to be able to update my object graph in memory including insertions (which happen instantly) and deletions (which do not).

Comment: Look into NSFetchResultsController, which is designed to work with table views. I think it will greatly enhance your experience with Core Data. Also, there's a great video on Apple's developer site (login required). Let me see if I can find a link.

Comment: Thanks Moshe! Your advice is appreciated. The conversion to using CoreData has brought some big benefits but also has been a bit of a headache. Its hard to use an object graph for your core datastructures without true "ordered list" support, and not being able to delete objects in memory was a bit of a shock to me. I'm sure there is a sensible reason as to why it works this way, although I'm not sure what it is. Apple's documentation on Core Data did recommend doing a save after every user interaction with the database, so that is what I am doing now.

Comment: Thanks, you save my day:)

Answer (score 0):

I think Core Data want to minimize memory & IO usage while `deleteObject:`, and do all the heaver jobs, like write sqllite file, in `save:`. That could be the most time-efficient way.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I'm still confused. I've experimented a bit more, and the behaviour I reported above happens sometimes and not others. I don't really care about what happens under the covers, but when I delete an object, it needs to at least appear to be deleted to my app (i.e. I would expect that the deleted object would not show up anywhere unless I looked hard for it such as looking in the deletedObjects list returned by NSManagedObjectContext.